# When to use lambda when evaluating Time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, lambda

I was given the advice to

> enclose the 'where' in a lamda because Time.now is evaluated when the
>   class loads, not when the method is called so if your app runs for
>   more than a month you will start to get incorrect results.

Example:

```
scope :from_this_month, where("vote.created_at > ? AND vote.created_at < ?", Time.now.beginning_of_month, Time.now.end_of_month)
```

To

```
scope :from_this_month, lambda { where("votes.created_at > ? AND votes.created_at < ?", Time.now.beginning_of_month, Time.now.end_of_month) }
```

I have various functions that use time in their calculations and to determine if they need to run.

Will these functions work correctly and if not how would I include a lambda to get the desired output even after the app has been running for a month?

Scope in a model

```
scope :from_this_month, where("votes.created_at: Time.now.beginning_of_month, (Time.now.end_of_month))
```

In a rake task that runs every day to check if it must send reports to a particular business

```
task :send_reports => :environment do
if Time.now.monday? && (business.report_schedule == 'monday')
...
end
```

Method in a model

```
employee.votes.exists?(phone_id: self.phone_id, created_at: 7.days.ago..DateTime.now)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scopes are evaluated when the class is loaded. A production server for example loads the code once and runs with the same evaluated time until the server is reloaded or restarted. Therefore you should use lambdas in scopes.

When you have a query in a method or a rake task than the code evaluated every time. Therefore  you do not need to use lambdas in that case.

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding you should use lambda when creating named scopes. See https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide#activerecord for example. Scroll a little down to get to the lambda section. Using lambda causes whatever is inside the block to be lazy loaded, meaning that it won't be evaluated until it is called.